# SharePoint Admin Port Configuration

Tags: administration, central-administration

Is there a particular configuration file from which the administrative port number of a SharePoint installation can be read from?

What I want is to get the administrative port number of a given SP installation programmtically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically their is no configuration file for this 
 you can use stsadm command to get portnumber

> stsadm -o getadminport

if you want use it using object model kindly use

SPAdministrationWebApplication details are provide at link below (this will give you url from which you can extract the port number

```
        SPAdministrationWebApplication caWebApp = Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAdministrationWebApplication.Local;
   url = caWebApp.Sites[0].Url;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spadministrationwebapplication_members.aspx